# What's the best way of instance a variable of same name but different type based on switch result

Tags: c#

Obviously the following code is wrong because of multiple declarations of compareItem variable.
But for the sake of understanding this is how I want this code work.

```
switch (objectType)
        {
            case "Armor":
                Item compareItem = player.armor;
                break;
            case "Shield":
                Item compareItem = player.shield;
                break;
            case "Medikit":
                Item compareItem = player.medikit;
                break;
            case "Grenade":
                Item compareItem = player.grenade;
                break;
            case "Weapon":
                Item[] compareItem = player.weapons;
                break;
            case "Bullet":
                Item [] compareItem = player.bullets;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
```

What is the best way to make possible instantiate compareItem like a Item class or an array of Item class based on the result of the switch?

Comment: Why do you use `Item` and `Item[]`? It seems that you don't need the array.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm guessing because there's multiple weapons and multiple bullets.

Comment: yep player.weapons and player.bullets are both Item array

Comment: The answer really depends on what are you doing next with result. If you are going to check items (disregards if it's one or multiple returned by e.g. `"Weapon"`) then @TimSchmelter answer is the way to go. If however you will do something differently, then Rahul answer is the way (you can add flag variable or simply check for `null` to see which array to use).

Comment: you are right. The motivation of this question was to know if there is a way other than Tim and Rahul solution but seems not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `dynamic` in here. For Example

```
      dynamic compareItems;
      switch (objectType)
      {
       case "Armor":
          compareItems = new Item[]{ player.armor };
          break;
       case "Shield":
          compareItems = new Item[]{ player.shield };
          break;
       case "Medikit":
          compareItems = new Item[]{ player.medikit };
          break;
       case "Grenade":
          compareItems = new Item[]{ player.grenade};
          break;
       case "Weapon":
          compareItems = player.weapons;
          break;
       case "Bullet":
          compareItem = player.bullets;
          break;
       default:
          return;
      }
```

Comment: This is the answer I looking for.

Comment: This solution is simply horrible...and so is the scenario in the first place.

Comment: I am a newbie in stackoverflow that's why I don't know the code beautification like you @InBetween

Comment: Whoever talked about code beautification? This code is simply horrible because it doesn't help at all with the problem at hand (the code following the `switch` statement will still have to somehow discern and handle `item` and `item[]` differently) and is therefore a blatant and pointless abuse of `dynamic`. This code would not pass a simple code review anywhere. But, as I said, the solution isn't the only thing wrong here, the question itself is a coding horror.

Answer (score 5):

You could use one variable. Since you use `Item[]` and `Item` you could use one `Item[]` for both. In case of armor, shield, medikit and grenade it contains only one item:

```
Item[] compareItems = null;
switch (objectType)
{
    case "Armor":
        compareItems = new Item[]{ player.armor };
        break;
    case "Shield":
        compareItems = new Item[]{ player.shield };
        break;
    case "Medikit":
        compareItems = new Item[]{ player.medikit };
        break;
    case "Grenade":
        compareItems = new Item[]{ player.grenade};
        break;
    case "Weapon":
        compareItems = player.weapons;
        break;
    case "Bullet":
        compareItems = player.bullets;
        break;
    default:
        return;
}
```

Your logic must handle the array anyway.